# React code doesn't display error when status code is 500

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api

React code status read fail, hence doesn't display any error when status code is 500

```js
  try {
                const res = await axios({
                  method: "post",
                  url: `${landslide}`,
                  data: formData,
                  headers: {'Content-type': "multipart/formData"}
                });
                console.log("hello", res);
                if (res.data.status === 200) {
                  swal("success", res.data.message, "success").then(function() {
                    navigation("/landslide");
                  });
                } else if (res.data.status === 500) {
                  swal("warning", res.data.message, "warning").then(function() {
                    navigation("/landslide");
                  });
                }
              } catch (error) {
                swal("warning", "please check your form's input", "warning").then(function() {
                    navigation("/landslide-report");
                  });
              }

          }
```

Comment: What is the error? Show the full code, because if you are using AJAX, then you should never have `true` in `} else if (res.data.status === 500) {`, as another part should have run... share the full code please and what is happening (errors)

Comment: i'm using axios for it

Answer (score 0):

Set `try` & `catch` method for better catching errors.

```
try { 
  await getData();
} catch (error) {
 if(error.response.status === 500) { // your error
   // your code for that particular error
 }
}
```

Comment: I did set try and catch too but when status code is 500 it still didn't display any error but in console it did